# Correct way of assigning to the innerHTML

Tags: javascript

Why does this line of code work?

```
var elem = document.getElementById("button");
elem.firstChild.innerHTML = "Enable";
```

But this doesn't?

```
var elem = document.getElementById("button").firstChild.innerHTML;
elem = "Enable";
```

Comment: because `innerHTML` is an attribute of the node which you have to set explicitly.

Comment: Because in the last code block, elem **is a copy** of the HTML content of the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var elem = document.getElementById("button");
elem.firstChild.innerHTML = "Enable";
```

Here you are changing the innerHTML of an element.

```
var elem = document.getElementById("button").firstChild.innerHTML;
elem = "Enable";
```

You are storing the innerHTML to elem and are simply changing local variable in the code above.

You can put everything in a single line and would not even need the temp variable.

```
document.getElementById("button").firstChild.innerHTML = "Enable";
```

should also work fine.

Comment: I needed to reference my button several times so I thought a variable would be better. But thank you for the clarification.

Comment: If you want to refer the same element and change the innerHTML, you can create a function that accepts the new value for innerHTML and update the innerHTML inside the function.

Comment: Good idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using `innerHTML` without assignment returns the current inner HTML of the object.

Using it with assignment inserts new HTML into the element.

You're assigning the innerHTML in the first function, but returning the inner innerHTML in the second function.

See this documentation for details https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

Your first snippet:

1. Finds the DOM element and stores it as the variable `elem`
2. Sets the `firstChild.innerHTML` property of the DOM element to `"Enable"`

---

Your second snippet:

1. Finds the DOM element and stores its `firstChild.innerHTML` property as the variable `elem`
2. Changes `elem` to now hold the string `"Enable"`

The `elem` variable is not linked to the DOM element in any way, it just holds a copy of the `innerHTML` property.

Answer (score 0):

```
var elem = document.getElementById("button");
elem.firstChild.innerHTML = "Enable";
```

In this code block you are assigning element as object into "elem" variable and we can access properties of object from it because of var can hold any type of data and it is holding first button element now.

```
var elem = document.getElementById("button").firstChild.innerHTML;
elem = "Enable";
```

In this code block you are assigning "innerHTML" of first button and innerHTML is returning value as string, so "elem" variable is of string type now and we can do any thing that is possible with string type, but it is not related to 
first button element here that is why it is not updating or setting innerHTML for first button element, elem is holding innerHTML  value not first button element.

we can set innerHtml by the following ways.

```
 $("#demo").html("Hello World By Id selector using html function");
        $('.demo').html('hello world By class selector using html function');
        $('#demo').text('Hello world By Id selector using text function');
        $('.demo').text(' Hello World By class selector using text function');
        $('div').html(' Hello World By element name selector using html function');
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World By Id selector using innerHTML property";
```

where element is.

```
 <div id="demo" class="demo"></div>
```